# How can i show where im moving the object in excel?

Tags: excel

im sorry it's a stupid question but i want my shapes to  be consistent
how can i show this while moving the shape in excel?
[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NtpQh.png)

Comment: Excel doesn't give that functionality, but with VBA you could access the `Top` and `Left` property of a shape.

Comment: Thank you for commenting. I would really appreciate it if you could reference a source for the method. I looked online and I couldn't find something related.

Comment: Here is the documentation on shape objects in Excel VBA: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.shape . Once you get a reference to a shape you can read off its position properties.